# How can a specific nuget package target be used?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a .net framework 4.7.2 project, which needs to reference a nuget package that has targets for both net framework 4.5.2 and net standard 2.0. The project also references other net framework projects, so I can't just retarget the project to net standard yet.

I'm trying to reference [Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Core/) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/) 2.1.1 from a net472 project. The net452 version of `Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Core` has a restriction `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 1.1.1 && < 2.0.0)` while the netstandard2.0 version of has a restriction of `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 2.0.1)`

Due to this dependency restriction, I need to use the netstandard version. net472 should be able to use both net452 and netstandard2.0 packages, but when a package targets both, it wants to use the net452 version by default.

How can I choose the target of the package to use?  With `packages.config` there was a `targetFramework` attribute, but I don't know what to use with `PackageReference`.

Comment: You cannot do that with NuGet. NuGet will use the assembly that is matches your project's target framework. You would have to reference the netstandard assembly directly instead of using NuGet - which probably will not help if you are using PackageReferences. Do you have more information on `Because of the dependency restrictions of the net framework version of the package, I need to use the net standard version`?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the package has both a net452 and a netstandard2.0 asset and you are targeting net472, the closest asset is the net452 one.

You can see this [here](http://nugettoolsdev.azurewebsites.net/4.3.0-preview4/get-nearest-framework?project=net472&package=net452%0D%0Anetstandard20).

If you want to use the netstandard2.0 asset the easiest option would be to directly reference the netstandard2.0 asset via a dll reference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll raise this with the package author to see if they can just add a net47 target and on one of the dotnet GitHub repositories to see if there's a better solution than referencing specific dlls directly.